# operator overload <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Code:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BmvMessage& bm);
```

I don't see anything incorrect, but it gives the following error:

> error: `std::ostream& BMV::BmvMessage::operator<<(std::ostream&, const BMV::BmvMessage&)' must take exactly one argument.

I do not know why this happens. Any suggestions are welcome. I have done this before and never came across this error. I have also checked online and it looks like:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, char c );`
```

Comment: Are you talking about a free function or a member function?

Comment: Err is that your declaration code? if so can you show the class?

Comment: ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const BmvMessage& bm); yeah can you see something wrong?

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: For future reference: That would have been a pretty important fact to include in your question!

Comment: @Kerrek SB yeah sorry, can you see why this error is being displayed?

Comment: Please provide a **complete**, minimal program. A complete program is one that we can compile exactly as-is and get the same error as you. A minimal program is one with all of the lines removed that are unrelated to your problem. See http://sscce.org to see why this is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take `operator<<` outside the class, making it a free function. Make it a `friend` of the class if it needs access to `private` parts.

Comment: Better have a public `toString` function and not need `friend`ship

Comment: @Benoit: depends on what the class looks like.

Comment: namespace BMV
{

 typedef STD::vector<BmvMessage*> BmvMessage_v_t;


 class BmvMessage : public DboGenBmvMessage
 {
  

 private :
 COM::FldInt _element;


 public :
  DCS_DEF_CLASS(BmvMessage)


  void getMessages(const COM::FldString Msg);
  void copyElements();


 };


;


}
#endif

Comment: that is wat the class looks like the post above

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: I was referring to Benoit's comment. My advice still stands.

Answer (score 3):

The operator has to be a *free* function, because its first argument is not of the same type as your class. In general, when you overload a binary operator `Foo`, the member function version only takes a single argument, and `FOO(a, b)` means `a.Foo(b)`.

Since `a << b` would invoke `a.operator<<(b)`, but `a` is the stream, this is of no use for us.

So make a free function, or perhaps a free friend function. Having a public `toString` member function can help:

```
class Foo {
public:
  std::string toString() const;
  // ...
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const Foo & x) {
  return o << x.toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the free form signature to define a member function. Member functions have an implicit `this` argument, so in your case your member function attempt at overloading `operator <<` would result in a function that takes 3 arguments: implicit `this`, `std::ostream&` os and `BmvMessage const&` bm.

You can't define streaming operators as members, since the first argument needs to be of stream class. Instead, you define them as free functions, possibly friended if needed.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that implicit `this` arguments don't play a role here.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: They don't, that was my point. I guess I was not clear enough